# How to optimize point cloud rendering in Qt3D

Tags: c++, qt, point, qt3d

I'm trying to display large point clouds (~20M pts) with Qt3D.

I first found this library https://github.com/MASKOR/Qt3DPointcloudRenderer which is a good example, but I rewrote a minimalist example to load a specific LAS or PCD point cloud and display it with a subclass of `Qt3DRender::QGeometry`.

It works and the point cloud is nice, but it **lags a lot**. I think there is no optimization and all 20M points are displayed all the time.

**What can I do to optimize this?**

(The same point clouds is fluid on the same laptop with other softwares such as QuickTerrainReader, Pix4D or even VTK.)

Currently, at loading, the point cloud is serialized into 2 `Qt3DRender::QBuffer`, and I create 2 attributes from there:

```
Qt3DRender::QAttribute* vertexAttrib = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(nullptr);
vertexAttrib->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
vertexAttrib->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
vertexAttrib->setVertexSize(3);
vertexAttrib->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
vertexAttrib->setBuffer(m_vertexBuffer);
vertexAttrib->setByteStride(12);
vertexAttrib->setByteOffset(0);
vertexAttrib->setCount(m_pointcloud->size());
addAttribute(vertexAttrib);
setBoundingVolumePositionAttribute(vertexAttrib);

t3DRender::QAttribute* colorAttrib = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(nullptr);
colorAttrib->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultColorAttributeName());
colorAttrib->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedByte);
colorAttrib->setVertexSize(3);
colorAttrib->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
colorAttrib->setBuffer(m_colorBuffer);
colorAttrib->setByteStride(3);
colorAttrib->setByteOffset(0);
colorAttrib->setCount(m_pointcloud->size());
addAttribute(colorAttrib);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a [`QFrustumCulling`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qfrustumculling.html) node to you framegraph? I don't think Qt3D is at the top performance-wise but maybe that helps.

Comment: Yes I have tried with FrustumCulling but I did not see a big improvement. 
In theory, I guess it should help when only a subpart of the point cloud is displayed. 
But what how to also improve performance when the whole cloud is shown? 
I didn't manage to find in VTK source code whether they apply an algorithm to discard points before filling the buffers, or if they use some shaders.
Thanks !